# CMake - Depending on another cmake project

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I have the following structure to a project I am working on:

```
---Library1
------build
------include
------src
------CMakeLists.txt
---Library2
------build
------include
------src
------CMakeLists.txt
---Executable1
------build
------include
------src
------CMakeLists.txt
```

`Library1` is a library I am developing that needs to link with `Library2` which is a 3rd party library. When I build `Library1`, I need it to automatically build `Library2` and link with it. `Executable1` will need to build and link with `Library1`. I'm not sure how to do with with Cmake, and I was wondering if anyone could guide me in the right direction. I think I may need to use the `add_dependencies` command or `add_subdirectory` but I'm not sure how to go about using them and making sure they are linked to my library. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd think the best commands here are likely to be [`add_subdirectory`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aadd_subdirectory) (as you suspected) and [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries).

I guess with your directory structure, I'd expect to see a "top-level" CMakeLists.txt in the root.  In that CMake file, you'd invoke the subdirectories' CMakeLists using `add_subdirectory`.

I imagine both `Library1` and `Library2` are actual CMake targets, included via `add_library`, and similarly you have `add_executable(Executable1 ...)`.  In this case, you can add the following to Library1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(Library1 Library2)
```

CMake now automatically links `Library2` whenever `Library1` is specified as a dependency.  If `Library2` is modified, then it will be rebuilt automatically before being linked to `Library1` again.

Likewise in Executable1/CMakeLists.txt you can then do:

```
target_link_libraries(Executable1 Library1)
```

Probably the only thing to watch for here is that the order of the `add_subdirectory` commands would need to be

```
add_subdirectory(Library2)
add_subdirectory(Library1)
add_subdirectory(Executable1)
```

so that the dependencies are defined *before* they're referred to in the `target_link_libraries` calls.

A final point which seems odd to me is that you have a build directory per target.  Normally there should only be a need for a single build directory (preferably outside the source tree).

Comment: In Brad's case I would have `Executable/build/linux` and `Executable/build/win32`. all libraries were built inside `Executable/build/XXX`.

Comment: @Fraser : How do you send e.g. `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to all of these subdirectories? e.g. all of my libs need to call cmake with PREFIX_PATH to find some packages. it seems simply using add_subdirectory is not enough and the callers CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH does not get propagated to all subsequtent CMakeLists.

Comment: If i have 3 libraries, and Library2 requires Library1, and Library3 requires Library2 and Library1, then when it tries to compile Library3 I get "Cannot find -lLibrary1". How am I supposed to structure this?