# CMake, prebuild SDL2 (and other dependencies) if needed

Tags: cmake

Actually I'm pretty happy that SDL2 compiles out of the box when CMake is invoked using GCC as compiler. Software should always be so simple to build, but I want more.

Assume I have all my software in a directory tree like that:

```
F:/GIT/SDL2_0_3
F:/GIT/myProject
```

What I want to achieve, is calling CMake

```
F:/GIT/myProject/build/XXX> cmake ../../ -G "GeneratorName"
```

and obtain

```
F:/GIT/myProject/bin/XXX/libMyProject.dll
F:/GIT/myProject/bin/XXX/libSDL2.dll
F:/GIT/myProject/build/XXX/projectfile
```

XXX is the name of the target (a variable I added):

```
-DTARGET_NAME:STRING="XXX"
```

Is it possible to "add_subdirectory( SDL)" so that I can just delegate everything to

```
F:/GIT/SDL2_0_3/CMakeLists.txt
```

Actually I have to build SDL apart, but it's a bit tedious going into X folders to have X different SDL binaries (and repeat X for each depedency because I'm not limited to SDL, actually a Batch script is doing that for me, but I want to move to Cmake since its portable).

I have a folder with all libraries I use and projects (F:/GIT) so I cannot use a CMakeLists.txt file in the following position:

```
F:/GIT/CMakeLists.txt
```

so this question is not a duplicate of: [Depending on another CMake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725657/cmake-depending-on-another-cmake-project) (I require a different answer since the other one is not enough)

P.S:

I specifically need multiple targets because I'm cross compiling and supporting also several version of certain compilers (because binaries of different compiler versions would just crash ... GCC u.u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally found an answer:

```
add_subdirectory( ../SDL2_0_3 ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/SDL2)
```

First I have to use a relative path so I go back by 1 directory level with `../` then I specify the folder I'm interested in, `SDL2_0_3`. Then since the source directory is outside my project I have to specify a new binary directory (2nd argument of `add_subdirectory`).

I cannot use:

```
${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
```

Because I would get simliarly named Cmake's metafile (and hence each one overrides the other), so I have to go a little bit deeper

```
${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/SDL2
```

But now the problem is that shared libraries are sparse around so I have to copy the DLLs where required.

In build directory:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET SDL2 POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:SDL2> 
    "../../build/${TARGET_NAME}/$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:SDL2>"
)
```

In testing directory:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET SDL2 POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:SDL2> 
    "../../build/${TARGET_NAME}/tests/$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:SDL2>"
)
```

In binary release directory:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET SDL2 POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:SDL2> 
    "../../bin/${TARGET_NAME}/$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:SDL2>"
)
```

The only bad point is that building SDL from CMake-Gui requires somewhat like 10 seconds, while building it from scripts requires ~5 minutes (I guess because from GUI they do unity build). I don't want to mess with SDL script so I hope they fix that soon.