# CMakeLists with multiple CMakeLists under it in build tree

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following tree:

```
/all-targets
----CMakeLists.txt
----/target1
--------CMakeLists.txt
--------/include
--------/src
----/target2
--------CMakeLists.txt
--------/include
--------/src
----/target3
--------CMakeLists.txt
--------/include
--------/src
```

the top-level CMake should be able to link all the targets together without producing any executable or library file, only generating any project type with the correct structure/tree

the target1 needs to have a library/object file from target2 so it can be compiled.

I've read those: 1. [Multiple CMakeLists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150576/multiple-cmakelists)
                 2. [CMake - Depending on another cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725657/cmake-depending-on-another-cmake-project)

What I understand now is in the top-level CMakeLists.txt I can add `add-subdirectory` command to add the target1, target2, and target3 (child directories) but I still don't understand what should I add in /target1/CmakeLists.txt so it can be linked with target2 library file ? I don't think it's `add-subdirectory` because in this case the target2 directory is sibling not child/sub directory.

Would the top-level CmakeLists.txt file understand that I want only to create the project file linking the targets together without having an output (executable - library).

Comment: What kind of targets are these? Are they all standalone executables? Static libraries? Will they be used separately or linked together in a final top-level executable/library?

Comment: "what should I add in /target1/CmakeLists.txt so it can be linked with target2 library file ?" - Assuming your have targets `target1` and `target2` created in corresponded directories, you need to add `target_link_libraries(target1 target2)`. "top-level CMake should be able to link all the targets together without producing any executable or library file" - I don't understand that. *Linking* is part of the process which produces something (an executable or a library). Could you add context of `CMakeLists.txt` files into the question post? This could help to undertand your intention.

Comment: @Botje yes they are standalone executables and can be used as static libraries too with another targets, also they will be used separately and all together with the top-level. (the top-level is only to produce .i.e. the xcode project containing all these targets

Comment: @Tsyvarev what I meant is the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` should be able to produce .i.e. Xcode project contains all the targets together. I don't if I'm able to explain my thoughts in a correct way :\

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given us much to go on, but I can provide a general idea.

The top-level CMakeLists simply calls `add_subdirectory` on the various targets. These should be sorted such that no target depends on targets *after* it.

For target1 you can have the following:

```
add_library(target1_common STATIC oven.cpp pan.cpp tray.cpp)
target_include_directories(target1_common PUBLIC include)
add_executable(target1 target1_main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(target1 PRIVATE target1_common)
```

You said that target2 depends on some parts of target1, so:

```
add_library(target2_common STATIC table.cpp chair.cpp plate.cpp)
target_include_directories(target2_common PUBLIC include)
target_link_libraries(target2_common PUBLIC target1_common)

add_executable(target2 target2_main.cpp)
target_link_libaries(target2 PRIVATE target2_common)
```

The executables are linked `PRIVATE` because you will not further link to them, but `PUBLIC` will work as well.

EDIT: Added `target_include_directories` statements that automatically populate the header search path for `target1_common` and `target2_common`

Comment: So if I added `target_link_libraries(target2_common PUBLIC target1_common)` only, the `/target2/CMakeLists.txt` will search for `target1_common` without specifying the search paths for it right ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "search for". CMake will compile the static library `target1_common` and mark it as a dependency of `target2_common` for when it is linked into `target2`.

Comment: what if I need to include the headers of target1_common ? the command you've added will get the headers of target1_common ?

Comment: Yes. PUBLIC and INTERFACE include paths are propagated when linking.